# Android app analytics demographics

Tags: android, analytics

I have implemented the code as follows however I am not seeing any demographics appear.

```
  GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
```

I get screen hits and clicks and real time users and such but no demographics
please help

UPDATE: 
To help close this question my only solution was to "Hurry up and wait" after about 3 days the data began rolling in. Please note that if you userbase is small you may not be able to see the user data for privacy reasons

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: My question is what do I need to do to get demographic reports working from google analytics. I have implemented the code above and enabled it in my admin analytics console. Its been about a week still no data in those reports.

Comment: same problem here.. any working solutinos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to go over the **Enable Demographic reports in the Analytics interface** section in [this Google Analytics documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948).

Important steps from the documentation:

- Open the Demographics Overview report, then click Enable above the
  introductory text.
- Click Admin, select the property you want, click Property
  Settings, then under Display Advertiser Features, enable the option for Demographics and Interests Reports.

***With the reports enabled and the tracking-code modification in place, you should see data in your reports within 24 hours.***

Comment: It has been over 24 hours still nothing and I have enabled the demographics still nothing.

Comment: im having the same problem

Comment: To help close this question my only solution was to "Hurry up and wait" after about 3 days the data began rolling in. Please note that if you userbase is small you may not be able to see the user data for privacy reasons.